# parseerror in jQuery when returning xml from mod_python

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, mod-python

I'm trying to return XML-data from a Python script using jQuery's .ajax:

```
<html><head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.py/method",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) { alert('Success!'); },
        error: function(request, error) { alert(error); }
      });
    });
   </script>
 </head><body></body></html>
```

When my `script.py` returns nothing the alert show `Success!`, but as soon as I try to add some XML data all I get is `parseerror`. How should I do to return XML without getting a parseerror?

*script.py - working*

```
def method(req):
    req.content_type = 'text/xml'
    req.write('')  # Works!
```

*script.py - broken*

```
def method(req):
    req.content_type = 'text/xml'
    req.write('<item>1</item><item>2</item>') # parserror!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml isn't valid, you are missing a root node(a single root node), eg

```
def method(req):
    req.content_type = 'text/xml'
    req.write('<items><item>1</item><item>2</item></items>')
```

Comment: So obvious.. I was looking another direction :)